# On click of next button, based on radio button choice, how to redirect steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my step by step wizard in bootstrap, I want to be able to change the step that it goes to.
This is the code I'm using 
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e3MBM .
Except that on the first step I have a radio button :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="assessmentType" class="control-label">Choose type</label> 
    <div class="row col-sm-12">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="female" value="Female" name="radio">Female
        </label>

        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="male" value="Male" name="radio">Male
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that when the Male is chosen it redirects to step-3 and when female is chosen it redirects to step 2 ?

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val();
switch (val) {
    case 'female':
        //show step 2 ?
        break;
    case 'male':
        //show step 3?
        break;
    default:
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLowerCase()` function for matching case sensitive string and hide all the steps before showing matched step

**JS code**

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val();
val = val.toLowerCase(); //change the case with small for matcing

switch (val) {
  case 'female':
 //hide all steps
 //then show the step2
      break;
  case 'male':
   //hide all steps
 //then show the step3
      break;
  default:
}
```

Comment: What I actually was asking was how to hide all the steps and show step3, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase female and male:

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=path]:checked').val();
switch (val) {
    case 'Female':
        //show step 2 ?
        break;
    case 'Male':
        //show step 3?
        break;
    default:
}
```